# How to get files from a Cordova 2.2.0 app on iOS

Tags: cordova, file-transfer

I've got a couple of CSV files that I've generated in my app, and I'm looking for a viable way to get the files to a desktop computer so some good ol' fashioned number crunching can happen.  For the time being, the files have to stay CSV, as that's what the desktop application uses.  I see that there is a file transfer method, but it looks like it submits the file using post, but I don't want this software to have any sort of web service dependencies.  I was thinking of using email, but it looks like I can't add attachments.  What would work out really well would be a nice FTP client, but I've only been able to find a plugin for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Posting to a web service is easiest, because that is supported directly by the browser, no plugins needed.

There are iOS FTP client librariess available, but there is a fair bit of complexity involved there.

Email on the other hand is a standard part of iOS, so even if the standard plugin doesn't do the structure you want, writing a custom email plugin is pretty straightforward:

```
-(void)sendEmail:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options  
    {

    NSString *callback = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *html = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *csv= [arguments objectAtIndex:3];

    NSData *csvData = [csv dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [composer setSubject:@"CSV Data"];
    [composer setMessageBody:html isHTML:YES];
    [controller addAttachmentData:csvData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"CSVFile.csv"];


    if (composer != nil) {
        [self.viewController presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES];
    }
   // [composer release]; // not needed with ARC

    // send callback immediately - we don't need to know what happened to the mail after the UI opened

    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:  @"Email UI opened"];    
    [self writeJavascript:[result toSuccessCallbackString:callback]];

}   

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{       
    [self.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}
```